# Export artifacts (e.g. bitmaps) from automated tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, teamcity, xunit.net

When executing automated tests of an application, which is able to display drawings, it would sometimes be helpful to take a look at the produced drawings when a test fails. Especially, if the application is built on a CI server the produced drawings are valuable artifacts, which would help resolving failing tests.

Is there any native support for this or do we have to implement this manually? We use xUnit.net as our testing framework and TeamCity as our CI server.

Do you have any general thoughts or concerns on creating artifacts from automated tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no general concerns on creating artefacts from within process.

Teamcity has built in support for picking up artefacts from within a build step. What you nee to do however is declare what the definition of artefacts is . You need to do take care of 2 things

1. On the general settings of your build target, define the "artefact path"  where you artefact can be found. This helps teamcity to figure out which files to pick up
2. I would recommend changing your build process slightly so that you can write all your artefacts into a zip file with an index.html page (this is the standard setting for teamcity) . You can then define a custom name for your artefacts in the "administration" -> "Integration" ->"Report Tabs" section.

Once you do both the above steps and run a target , you can see a custom menu in the dropdown for every build where you can see all your test artefacts.

Answer (score 1):

[Approval Tests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net) might help for that.